# What are the legal requirements for an amateur radio satellite?

Tags: legal, satellites

Lets say I can throw a satellite into orbit (I've got a good arm). I'm amateur radio qualified so can I just set it up to transmit on an amateur band and start having fun? Is there anyone I have to register with? Or am I good to go with my own license? Do I need to contact the FCC or something like that?

Comment: I've edited your title so that it is specific about the question you're asking. Please feel free to edit further — I couldn't think of a really good phrasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the [IARU](http://www.iaru.org/satellite.html) attempts to regulate which amateur satellites use which amateur bands to transmit, who in turn coordinates transmission with the ITU. [Most countries](http://www.itu.int/en/about/Pages/default.aspx) have signed treaties with the ITU (a UN special agency) to not intentionally cause interference, etc. It looks like there are [370 cubesats currently registered](http://www.amsat.org.uk/iaru/) with the IARU.

If you plan on transmitting to the satellite, you will also need an amateur radio license (from the [ARRL](http://www.arrl.org/) if in the US), the version will depend on the frequency band operated in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and informative answer. Stack exchange at it's best!

Comment: Note that the FCC issues amateur licenses in the US, while the ARRL is the largest organized group of amateurs in the US.